# Web Services and Claim Based Authentication Problem

Tags: web-services, claims-based-auth, user, claims

I'm facing some problems accessing by Claim Based to my web service.

On my App there's only Claim Based: windows auth is disabled and NTLM also.
If I access to Sharepoint by web based interface, this recognise me as UserX and everything goes.

If I access by WS there are 2 scenarios:

- Call by UserY (System Account) -> Everything goes well
- Call by UserX (NO SA but SCAdmin) -> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The code is very simple, gets only current user Login Name:

```
using (SPSite sito = new SPSite("https://to0wss2k10rey03:50000/sites/Test1"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = sito.OpenWeb())
                {
                    string Username =  web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
                }
            }
```

The exception is raised when i try to get the CurrentUser, wich appears to be null..

Comment: Hmmm... where are you using the web services? This is plain 'ol server side OM code!? Do you run this in a console app, in a web part...? Which line do you get the null ref exception? Please provide us with more details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quiet mystified by how it works with UserY, it should always fail.

When running with Claims without NTLM the only way to pass credentials is through a FedAuth cookie with your SharePoint STS SAML token. To get that token you have to call the SharePoint STS with a SAML token from your identityprovider (ADFS?). To get that token you have to call the identity provider with login info.

See [Claims Proxy – A C# Library for Calling Claims Protected Web Services](http://www.huggill.com/2012/02/04/claims-proxy-a-c-sharp-library-for-calling-claims-protected-web-services/) [Connecting to SharePoint with Claims Authentication](http://fredericloud.com/2011/01/11/connecting-to-sharepoint-with-claims-authentication/) or the main blog about SharePoint with claims [Share-n-dipity](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/)